# authentication to github from Windows 10 VM

Tags: authentication, github, windows-10, virtual-machine

Is there any way I can authenticate on GitHub from my Windows 10 VM so that I can push the changes?

Right now the Edge is just sits there with the disabled button "Authenticate".

I know in Linux I can set the user id in some configuration file, but it looks like its not happening on Windows.

Is there any other way?

[image: Image demonstrating the issue]

Answer (score -1):

You should see a `Sign In` button when visiting https://github.com/login: that would allow you to authenticate on the remote side.

From your VM, using the latest Git for Windows, you will also authenticate when pushing for the first time to a GitHub repository: the credential helper will use the Windows credential manager to cache your GitHub credentials.

Comment: no it won't - the browser just sits there at the `Credentials`screen with the Authenticate button disabled. And yes - I'm logged in to GitHub with FF, IE and Edge, but pushing is still not possible.

Comment: @Igor Can you edit the question with a screenshot? I am not familiar with an "Authenticate" button.

Comment: the button is called `Authorize GitCredentialManager`. And it is disabled - continuously.

Comment: @Igor So... it is not "Authenticate", then. A screenshot would still be helpful.

Comment: screenshot added.as requested